# How does a faculty member get to work at two universities or more?

Tags: university, professorship, joint-appointment

This question is a follow-up on a comment at a [recent question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1836/when-does-one-go-for-a-double-doctorate), where Dave Clarke mentioned that an acquaintance of his has "3 professorships and 2 doctorates."

- How does a faculty member get appointed simultaneously by two or more universities? Are all except one honorary posts?
- Can any faculty member work with a second university with the consent of their present employer? What are the conflicts of interests that come into play usually?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The situation I've seen most often is that a professor will hold a primary appointment at school A, where they have a lab and complete their research. Often for reasons related to collaboration, school B will then give the professor an appointment in a related if not identical department. If the professor also teaches a few courses at school C, they will likely be granted an adjunct position there as well.

This was my setup when I was in graduate school; I was a grad student in bioengineering at [U Pitt](http://www.pitt.edu/), and I had a secondary appointment at [CMU](http://www.cmu.edu) due to both lab collaborations and my being registered in a [certificate program](http://www.cnbc.cmu.edu/) there.

Comment: Harvard/MIT/BU/Broad/Whitehead/MGH comes to mind.

Comment: How about the salary? Paid in full at all univs? Or is the pay suspended at the primary univ?

Comment: @Bravo - Most joint appointments are honorary/convenience titles, and do not come with pay (unless the faculty member takes on responsibilities, such as teaching). Adjunct teaching positions pay their own (typically pretty low) salary.

Answer (score 12):

Another common scenario happens when a professor leaves university X for university Y, but still has grants and PhD students at university X.  In that situation, it's fairly common for university X to keep the faculty member on the books without pay, possibly with the word "adjunct" added to their title, so that the students and the grants that pay them don't have to move from X to Y.  (And to simplify the paperwork if the professor changes their mind and moves back to X.)

Comment: "changes their mind" ? yikes.

Comment: Maybe it would be more politic to say "in case, when the professor finally makes up their mind, they decide to stay".

Comment: Yes, singular "they".  If it was good enough for Shakespeare....

Comment: No I was merely surprised that people change their minds. Faculty moves are painful.

Comment: It's not unusual for very highly sought after researchers to take a job for a year to try it out and then possibly keep the old job. It's not something that should be abused, or done often, but it's hardly the worst thing ever.

Comment: Speaking from more experience on this subject than I care to admit: it's quite normal when one moves from one TT position to another to stay on the books at your previous position as being on leave.  I would regard it as the default; there's no cost for the person moving and negligible for either department.

Comment: @Suresh People change their minds all the time.  One mathematician (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Ozsváth) has managed the pretty impressive feat of having TT positions at Berkeley, Columbia, MIT and Princeton in under a decade.

Answer (score 9):

Here in the Netherlands it is relatively common to appoint somebody as a professor for one day a week. For instance, one of the colleagues is 4 days a week at our university and 1 day a week at a different university. Another colleague is 4 days a week working for a company, and works at the university only on Mondays.

Answer (score 7):

A common scenario I've observed is where University A offers a job to a professor at University B, a far less prestigious and well-connected institution, but the professor and his/her family wish to remain in the location of University B for personal reasons.  If the professor is good enough, University A may agree to a half-time or similar arrangement, where the professor is only on-campus for one semester per year (usually 4 months).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the excellent answers given above, here are some reasons I've seen for professors to get an appointment at a different university (or to retain an appointment when they moved):

- They're a major part of a center at University A, and University A really doesn't want 'Co-Director of the A Center for Really Important Research' to be listed as a faculty member elsewhere.
- Weird university tradition. For example, my university automatically gives all outside readers on a dissertation committee an appointment at the school. It's utterly meaningless, but technically its a thing.
- Collaboration, grants, etc. are sometimes easier if everyone is technically faculty at the same school, and schools will sometimes bring in a professor from another nearby university to "shore up" a program, allow for easier mentorship if a professor keeps appearing on grad student committees, etc.