# Can one professor hold more than one endowed chair?

Tags: university, professorship, career-path

Are there examples of one person holding more than one endowed chair at the same university?

Comment: At the same university or at different universities simultaneously?

Comment: My answered assumed at the same university, otherwise this would be a duplicate of: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1999/how-does-a-faculty-member-get-to-work-at-two-universities-or-more?rq=1

Comment: I've edited it to clarify at the same university. Feel free to revert if you disagree.

Answer (score 14):

I had personally never heard of anyone occupying two endowed chairs at the same time at the same university. Even if a person had two appointments in separate departments at the same university (for example, History of Science and Psychology), they were usually listed as the:

- Dunning-Kruger Professor of Psychology and History of Science

or alternately, if the endowed line (the DK-Professorship) had been bequeathed specifically to Psychology for example:

- Dunning-Kruger Professor of Psychology, Professor of History of Science

So the short answer is: no.

But that being said, there are always exceptions. A little digging around at universities that have separate sub-units revealed that, at Harvard there is a person in History who holds two endowed chairs and one regular position:

- [Annette Gordon-Reed](http://history.fas.harvard.edu/people/annette-gordon-reed)

  - Charles Warren Professor of American Legal History at Harvard Law School
  - Carol K. Pforzheimer Professor at the Radcliffe Institute
  - [Harvard U. FAS] Professor of History

I personally think that this exception proves the rule since the three professorships are at nominally separate entities (HLS, Radcliffe I, and Harvard U FAS) that are under the singular Harvard conglomerate umbrella.