# Pursuing Ph.D. at two institutions simultaneously

Tags: research-process

I am enrolled in a Ph.D. program at a leading institute in India. However I am facing certain problems which are administrative in nature and hence want to restart my Ph.D. at another institute. I am seeking clarification on the possibility to pursue Ph.D. from two institutes simultaneously. For your reference, I have already completed the course work at the current institute.

Comment: Whether or not it's technically possible depends on the rules and policies of the institutions involved.  But  regardless of whether it's permitted, I can't imagine a situation in which it would be a good idea.

Comment: I don't understand. As by your description, it sounds like you want to stop being a PhD student at your current institution and transfer to a new institute, correct? In this case, you would not do two PhDs simultaneously. You would stop the first one and start another one (maybe transferring course credits, if that is possible).

Comment: If you can keep the old PhD going then your "problems which are administrative in nature" really are not problems anymore. Why torture yourself living two full-time study lives (plus other responsibilities?)

Comment: PhD's are not merit badges... more of them is not necessarily better.  See the responses to this question on [pursuing two PhD's simultaneously](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17232/is-doing-two-phds-a-good-path/17245)