# Is it possible (and also meaningful) to do two PhDs?

Tags: phd

During my PhD I have developed two different research projects in parallel. This was not planned from the beginning, it just happened this way. I am sure each of these could be presented as a PhD and I am thinking on the possibility of presenting both, one after the other one. Would that make sense?

I had a quick talk with my Professor although I didn't ask him about this option because I had the fear he would find it a bit arrogant. So first of all, I wanted to get to know if it is meaningful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See also: [Is it sensible to do two PhDs simultaneously?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/34423/10643)

Comment: You cannot obtain two Ph.D. degrees by carrying out two research projects in **the same field**, albeit in different topics – it just does not make sense. Ph.D. is a _per-discipline degree_ or a _per-field-of-study degree_ (the latter applies to interdisciplinary fields).

Comment: I am not sure you understand what a PhD is. In many disciplines (e.g. CS) you need multiple good publications (>3) to obtain a PhD. Thus, you have to work on many different projects (somewhat related but not entirely) to actually produce these publications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I understand my question is substantially different from the previous threat on this topic. In that one, the person is asking if it is worthy to work in this direction as a future plan. In mine, I already have two fully finished projects and I'm wondering whether presenting them both as PhDs is a good idea.

Comment: In addition to the earlier comments, I don't see how you can submit two PhD theses when you are only registered on one PhD course.

Comment: You don't need 2 PhDs, you only need 1 good one. Why not try to merge all this work into one, strong PhD dissertation?

Answer (score 0):

There are many more interesting groups you could present the second project to than a doctoral committee.

Go forth and publish.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, what kind of groups do you mean? Both projects are done at a university.

Comment: Conferences, peer-reviewed journals