# What is the difference between Dual, Joint, and Double PhDs?

Tags: phd

What I understand is, Dual/Double PhD is getting two PhDs writing only one thesis.
But what is a Joint PhD?

Also, what is the benefit of these types of PhDs?

Comment: I think it is best to think of them as marketing terms and not look for a deeper meaning. Depending on who you are talking to, both can mean the same or something entirely different and one of their main benefit seems to be to make a CV look more impressive outside of academia...

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/79875/20058