# Pursuing the second PhD in a better grad school?

Tags: phd

My university, from which I received my PhD degree, is not well recognized in the global arena. So, I feel that having PhD does not open any doors for me in an academic field globally, or even in a non-academic field (I mean that I am not getting more (job) opportunities after completing my PhD, and this I attribute to a non-recognized PhD degree that I have). However, currently I am doing well in academia - I have an adjunct position at the same university and publishing papers in top-tier journals in the field. My current goal is to get an international exposure and mobility, and find better environments for conducting research. Therefore I believe I need to pursue my second PhD in a top university. I was wondering whether I am eligible to do the second PhD in a similar filed, but in a top PhD program? If not, this means that the wrong decision that I made a couple of years ago to pursue a PhD in a "bad program" forces me to stuck in my "non-competitive place" ... not fair, I think.

Comment: see also: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/188914/i-am-going-to-complete-my-phd-in-latin-america-soon-should-i-enroll-for-a-secon, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/75817/second-phd-or-postdoc-and-their-effects-on-tenure-track-position

Comment: On one hand, you should focus on what you learned, not on the names present in your PhD title. Focus on that, *you* completed *your* PhD, no matter where.
On the other hand, if you succesfully completed a PhD, your decision was **not** the wrong one. 
"not fair, I think." Unfortunately life is not fair.  Disclaimer: by this I do not endorse being unfair or being unempathic.

Comment: @EarlGrey Thank you for your comment. Indeed, As I mentioned, I successfully completed PhD and now doing well in research. Personally, I don't pay attention to PhD title .. but what I learned from my experience, international academic field pays. Even if I am doing well in my research, in order to find a good postdoc position in the US, I need to have graduated from a top program and/or have great publications, connections. I have great publications, but it is not possible for me to find a better research environment because of "non-reputable" PhD title.

Comment: If you are publishing papers in the top-tier journals of your field, lack of recognition does not seem to be the problem. There are plenty of excellent scientists who chose  non-top tier universities for a variety of reasons. Your problem may be more your lack of interaction and collaboration with other researchers. Focus on that: visit conferences, other departments and give talks. w.r.t. non-academic job offers: EarlGrey answer says it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have an adjunct position at the same university and publishing
> papers in top-tier journals in the field

This means that doing a second PhD will not help you. Try to get fundings and contacts to visit a department abroad.

> I am not getting more (job) opportunities after completing my PhD

People in the private world are smart enough to understand that your focus is on the academia, not on getting a job, so they do not see you as an interesting candidate.

If you were sending 10s of applications per week, you would see a marked difference in your approach as well as in the response from potential employers. Are you sending 10s of applications per week?