# Will CS programs look favorably on an older applicant who already has a PhD?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, computer-science, second-degree

Let's say a recent math PhD in his early 30s realizes he's unlikely to land another postdoc after his current one ends, and he decides he really liked being a grad student and he really doesn't want to grow up and get a real job. He also really likes theoretical computer science and computational number theory.  Do you think computer science PhD programs would be weirded out by the fact that he already has a PhD, or would it be an asset, or neither?

Comment: Related: [Is doing two PhDs a good path?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17232/is-doing-two-phds-a-good-path)

Comment: Your chances to get into another phd program are smaller than epsilon.

Comment: If said hypothetical math PhD put themselves forward as a candidate for the reasons stipulated above: really liking being a grad student, really liking theoretical computer science, and having limited capacity to make use of a PhD in mathematics, I would have lots of concerns about their viability as a master's candidate.

Comment: See also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1836/when-does-one-go-for-a-double-doctorate and other questions tagged [tag:second-degree].  Keep in mind that a lot of institutions will, as a matter of policy, refuse to admit anyone as a PhD student who already has a PhD in the same or similar field (math and computer science are almost surely "similar" for this purpose).  That may give you some indication.